# stream audio from android phone to ubuntu

Tags: gnome, sound, bluetooth, android, stream

When the system boots to login screen and it connects to my android phone via bluetooth the audio streaming works perfectly but when I login to my account there is no audio streaming from my android phone. What should I do?

Comment: hold on did you try **not** connecting your phone via bluetooth when on login screen and waiting untill **logged in** to do so?